# is it possible to have multiple interceptor on a resource in WSO2 microgateway 3.1.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-gateway

I am trying to have multiple java interceptors on a resource. Only last interceptor is being called. 
Is multiple interceptor on resource supported?

```
paths:
  /public/rt/PING:
    get:
      description: ""
      operationId: PING
      x-wso2-disable-security: true
      x-wso2-throttling-tier: 6PerMin
      x-wso2-request-interceptor: java:org.mgw.interceptor.IDSAuthInterceptor
      x-wso2-request-interceptor: java:org.mgw.interceptor.IPFilterInterceptor
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/PING"
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/PING"
      security:
        - basicAuthentication: []
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple interceptors are not supported. It is possible to write the first interceptor to call the second interceptor. Then multiple interceptors will not require.